# How to read ArrayList from text file but every 3 lines

Tags: java

Here is the sample text file:

Brisbane
03163012
Australia
Tokyo
041022200
Japan

now I want to read three data together then put in different variables. Then take another three and so on.

```
location = brisbane;  
phoneNumber  = 03163012;
country = Australia;
```

Afterwards, passed into the constructor.

And there is a MAXIMUM LOCATION = 10 that have to be read

```
public boolean data()
{
boolean isValid = true;
boolean check = true;
int a = 0;

try
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(newFileReader("location.txt"));
    String data = reader.readLine();

    while (data != null && check)
    {
        if (a != MAX_NUMBER)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                ?????????
                locations.add(newLocation);
                a++;
            }
        else
            check = false;

        data =reader.readLine;
        }
}
reader.close();
}
```

Can anyone help me with this one. I dont know what should I write in ????
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this inside your for loop:

```
            locations.add(data);
            data = reader.readLine();
            if(data!=null) 
                phoneNumber.add(data);
            else
                break;
            data = reader.readLine();
            if(data!=null) 
                country.add(data);
            else
                break;
            a++;
```

You want to read 3 lines, and add to locations, then phoneNumber, then country. There's all kinds of other problems with your code though (like a misplaced `}` and `newFileReader`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the problem is there is only one ArrayList that store these location, phoneNumber and country.

Comment: Then add them all to `locations`. You've not indicated what ArrayLists you have and how you intend to store the 3 lines into them.

Answer (score 2):

Use Guava's method that reads file by lines and gives output as `List<String>`

[Files.readLines(java.io.File, java.nio.charset.Charset)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#readLines%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

**Using it will make your code look much simplier, you will get rid of all those `try-catch-finally` and file buffers.**

Iterate that list and use those strings as variables for:

```
location = brisbane;  
phoneNumber  = 03163012;
country = Australia;
```

iterating can look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            //it's you a mock
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    lines.add("a");
    lines.add("1");
    lines.add("aa");

    lines.add("b");
    lines.add("2");
    lines.add("bb");


            //Iterating String from file.
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i += 3) {

        String location = lines.get(i);
        String phoneNumber = lines.get(i + 1);
        String country = lines.get(i + 2);

                    //somehow use red variables
        System.out.println(location);
        System.out.println(phoneNumber);
        System.out.println(country);
    }
}
```

Note that in code above I filled my list, yours fill be filled after reading file.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is another object for location, so you can store your values like this:

```
String data = reader.readLine();
int counter = 0;
MyLocation newLocation = null;
while (data != null && ((counter/3) != MAX_NUMBER)){
    switch(counter % 3){
        case 0:
            newLocation = new MyLocation();
            newLocation.setLocation(data);
            break;
        case 1:
            newLocation.setPhone(data);
            break;
        case 2:
            newLocation.setCountry(data);
            locations.add(newLocation);
            newLocation = null;
            break;
    }
    counter++;
}

if(null != newLocation){
    //Error management
}
```

The MyLocation class will look like this:

```
private String location = null;

private String phone = null;

private String country = null;

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
```